# How to calculate the phrase similarity based on word2vec

Tags: word2vec

I have millions of sentences and want to get the phrase vector, so I can  calculate the phrase similarity. But the problem is that I don't know how to use word2vec to get phrase vector, or does anyone know other tools?

Answer (score 1):

The simplist way to do this is simply add each of the corresponding word vector elements together and renormalise the result, giving you a sentence vector.

In C#, do something like this:

```
var vec = new double[dims];
foreach (var key in sentence)
{
    var tmp = model[key];
    for (var i = 0; i < dims; i++)
        vec[i] += tmp[i];
}

double len = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < dims; i++)
    len += vec[i] * vec[i];

len = Math.Sqrt(len);
var normal = new double[dims];
for (var i = 0; i < dims; i++)
    normal[i] = vec[i] / len;

return normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the phrase similarity, you have to use word vectors (trained by using word2vec algorithm) to combine phrase vectors.

Here is how to use word2vec to get phrase vector: [How to calculate phrase similarity between phrases](https://bitbucket.org/yunazzang/aiwiththebest_byor)